# How do I find the the exact lat/lng coordinates of a polygon in bing maps

Tags: polygon, bing-maps

while browsing into a certain bing map application, i need to extract the coordinates of a polygon.
in the html, all i get is a the relative location of the polygon, and i need the  lat/lng coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PixelToLatLong() method to convert from pixel locations on the map to corresponding Lat/Long. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429564.aspx for details.